# Power BI Selected Visuals BookMark

Tags: powerbi

1.I have a bookmark built on selected visuals.

2. How to identify the selections used to create that bookmarK

Comment: Does this help?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-bookmarks#visibility-using-the-selection-pane

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarks only make certain selections in/visible so you can go through them and observe which one change their nature.
If you have only one, create one with full visibility to see which ones are being adjusted.

It's far from neat, like a list that you are probably looking for, but I'm not aware of any such option in PowerBI